# Error "<f:ajax> contains an unknown id" when used to render <rich:message>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, glassfish-3

This is my form:

```
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="3" >
            <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Primeiro nome:" />
            <h:inputText id="name" value="#{register.person.name}" >
                <f:ajax event="blur" render="m_name"  listener="#{register.validateName}" />                                        
            </h:inputText>
            <rich:message id="m_name" for="name" />
            //.. others fields
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</body>
```

When i try to execute on Glassfish gives the follow error :

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: <f:ajax> contains an unknown id 'm_name' - cannot locate it in the context of the component name
```

But if i change `<rich:message ..>` by `<h:message..>` it works (I want it works with rich:message because it returns an image and a message )

Why this is happening ? Never happened with me before, until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The RichFaces component reference](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_0_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Output_and_messages.html) tells this about the [`<rich:messages>`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_0_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Output_and_messages.html#sect-Component_Reference-Output_and_messages-richmessage):

> #### 13.1.1. Basic usage
>
> ...
>
> The `<rich:message>` component is **automatically** rendered after an Ajax request. This occurs without the use of an  component or a specific reference through the render attribute of the Ajax request source.

So, I'd just remove the `render` attribute on `m_name` and replace `<f:ajax>` by `<a4j:ajax>`.

```
<h:inputText id="name" value="#{register.person.name}" >
    <a4j:ajax event="blur" listener="#{register.validateName}" />
</h:inputText>
<rich:message id="m_name" for="name" />
```

If you want to explicitly specify it anyway, you can set `ajaxRendered="false"` on the `<rich:message>` component.

```
<h:inputText id="name" value="#{register.person.name}" >
    <f:ajax event="blur" listener="#{register.validateName}" render="m_name" />
</h:inputText>
<rich:message id="m_name" for="name" ajaxRendered="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a richfaces behavior to me.  I suspect you will have to file a bug report.

A work-around is to enclose the rich:message tag inside a rich:message tag inside a div tag, then give the div tag an id="m_name".